# Xamarin Android Table Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-tablelayout

Here is a cut-down version of the table layout im using. I'm trying to simulate a HTML percentage width by using a weightSum of 100 on the table and applying layout_weight on each view appropriately.

From my C# code I'm then looking to add each line item dynamically as new TableRow to the table layout. I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that the columns line up in the new rows. This is different to HTML, where columns are always the same width per row.

I've been messing around LayoutParameters to try and set a weight, but doesn't seem possible on a textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/pagetemplate">
<TableLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/idBasketTable"
    style="@style/pagetemplate">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="Options"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Product Name"
            style="@style/textViewHeader"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Qty"
            style="@style/textViewHeader"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Price"
            style="@style/textViewHeader"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<include
    layout="@layout/Menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then from my code I'm attempting something similar to this (cut down for simplicity). You'll notice my attempted LayoutParameter code commented out on each View as this was making them disappear all together from the layout. Not sure whether I should be concentrating on the layout styles of the row itself or the individual views?

Secondly, in the first row, I've tried to create a column that has no title. The line item rows will include a small delete button here, which is why I've tried to make an empty column. Is there a better way to do this rather than creating a textView (used for nothing) and setting to invisible?

```
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.idBasketTable);


        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 100)
        };

        TextView tv_ProductName = new TextView(this)
        {
            Text = item.ItemName//,
            // LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        };
        tv_ProductName.SetTextAppearance(this, Resource.Style.textViewDetail);

        TextView tv_Qty = new TextView(this)
        {
            Text = item.ItemQty.ToString()//,
            //  LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        };
        tv_Qty.SetTextAppearance(this, Resource.Style.textViewDetail);

        TextView tv_Price = new TextView(this)
        {
            Text = item.ItemPrice.ToString()//,
            // LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        };
        tv_Price.SetTextAppearance(this, Resource.Style.textViewDetail);

        ImageButton ib_Delete = new ImageButton(this)
        {
            //   LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        };

        //set the view values for the current row.
        ib_Delete.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.deleteitem);
        Guid itemID = item.ItemID;

        //assign the delete onclick event.
        ib_Delete.Click += delegate
        {
            deleteItem_OnClick(ib_Delete, itemID);
        };

        //add views to the row.
        tr.AddView(ib_Delete);
        tr.AddView(tv_ProductName);
        tr.AddView(tv_Qty);
        tr.AddView(tv_Price);

        //add the row to the table layout.
        tl.AddView(tr);
```

Hope this all makes sense, appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: TL;DR you really should try and make your question clearer and easier to read. Maybe add some headings or split into smaller questions. =)

Comment: I was about to suggest you add a bounty if it's this complicated but for that you'll need a bit more reputation points.